# How to change size of WPF Window dynamically?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Let's say we show some WPF Window and comes moment when we have to show some extra panel at the bottom.

What I want to do is to increase WPF Window size and center it again.

Any clue or samples?

Comment: What happens when the window is maximized?

Comment: It is not maximized in fact. It needs to be changed by height only because new panel appears at the bottom.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can programmatically change the size and location of the window, just set the appropriate Width and Height values for size and Top and Left for location. But it's even easier.

Following [this page](http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cnagel/2008/01/resizing-the-main-window-of-wpf-applications.html) you get

```
<Window x:Class="SizingTest.Window1" 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        Title="Window1" 
        Width="Auto" Height="Auto" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
```

to automatically adapt the window size to the content, and with the [help of this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/fi-FI/wpf/thread/db9d78bb-35f8-477f-b6ef-87d8dbb748bf) you can center the window again after the size was changed.

Comment: Thanks bro! The final settings I need are:  Width="721"   Height="Auto" SizeToContent="Height"

Answer (score 6):

if you want to resize at a specific size you can do the following:

If you want to resize the main window just write the following code.

```
Application.Current.MainWindow.Height = 420;
```

If you want to resize a new window other than the main window just write the following code in the .cs file of the new window.

```
Application.Current.MainWindow = this; 
Application.Current.MainWindow.Width = 420;
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Resizing the current window is very easy. You just need to change the `Width` and `Height` properties, respectively:

```
private void ChangeSize()
{
// set window size to 640x480 pixels (x, y)
    this.Width = 640;
    this.Height = 480;
}
```

This will update the window size immediately.

Alternatively, you may also use [`ScrollViewer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/scrollviewer-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) to create a scrollbar so that child content fits to the window, `Frame`, `UserControl`, or anything else.

Hope my solution helps.